# Sequence of events for Fuzzy search on html page

Tags: html, angularjs, database, post, get

I have a page html let's call it abc.html

There are AngularJS fields embedded in it.

I am now writing a GET and POST in scala which routes the fuzzy search arguments to the proper page on the server.

I am trying to understand the sequence in which things occur in order to implement a GET/POST requests (written in scala) which would happen when someone makes a search on the search bar on the abc.html page, and which would return elements from the database

Is it abc.html (search) --> http GET request --> backend ( AngularJS) --> Database?
In this case this would mean my http post or get request would pass in the html data model elements which would in turn hit the backend AngularJS controller page which in turn would hit the database, and the return ride would send the database results via an http request to the page?
Do I need to explicitly define my GET in terms of angular fields and the database model?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP uses request-response pairs. This means you don't have to make another request to return anything to the client, you just need to write the proper response. Other than that, your idea is fundamentally right. The process would look something like this:

1. Type something into the search form on your HTML page
2. Submit the search form to your backend. This creates a `GET` or `POST` request depending on your form element's `method` attribute.
3. *(At this point the browser is awaiting a response)*
4. As the request reaches the server, your backend code can capture its data and make a query to your database.
5. *(At this point the server is awaiting data from the database)*
6. The database returns its results, your backend code is free to format it into a response to the client's original request.
7. The client receives the response and you can use your frontend code to display it to the user.

Comment: what do you mean by "you just need to write the proper response" ? and would a fuzzy search make things different? or those filtered searches which show a dropdown of potential terms

Comment: What I mean is simply return the response formatted the way you want it to be, as opposed to the raw data you get from your DB. :) The use case is fairly irrelevant here, the basic idea is the same - send a request to the server and return whatever is appropriate for you :)